# How does the visual studio team (foundation) project work?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I want to do a visual studio team project with a friend of mine. I looked at the Team Explorer tab in visual studio but I don't understand some  of the words / terminologies there. For example, what is Source Control Explorer, Build Definitions etc.? I've already created a team project but how can I work on it? Where do I write code? I'm assuming that after I finish the code, the code is uploaded to something like xxxx.visualstudio.com and others can access my code files there. Am I correct? (I guess not)

On the other hand, How can I add people to my team? Visual Studio Online tells me to enter the username or the sign in address of the user. Is "sign in address" the Microsoft account of the user?

Comment: Try to stick to one-question-per-post in the future. These are pretty short, but multi-part questions are frowned upon.

Comment: OK, I see. I'll do it next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This applies to TFS, if you use Git it will be different:

**Source Control Explorer** is, well, how you look at source control. The primary thing you will do there is checkout projects.

**Build Definitions** is were you configure build server builds.

**Pending Changes** is where you check-in files you have changed locally

To work on your project, you have to create a workspace (using Source Control Explorer) that maps the repository to your local system. Then create your solution there, and to make things easy check "Add to source control". Otherwise, you need to manually mark it for addition (again, using Source Control Explorer).

Check-in using the pending changes tab. If you don't have your own TFS server (sounds like you don't) then the code will be uploaded to an online server. I'm not aware of any web interface, but there could be one.

You will add other users based on their Microsoft account in the online scenario, and via TFS or Active Directory users if you are on a local TFS server.

Comment: I think I understands most of it. Thanks!